# TableView Delegate - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

In the below code I have tableview delegates, but initially when I select a row I want for the action in editActionsForRowAt to return a empty array. So basically **how can I call the editActionsForRowAt func and return an empty nil?**

The code is attached below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    var action:[UITableViewRowAction] = []

        let update = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Update", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

            DemosClient.sharedInstance.sendIdwhenUpdate()

           // let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoadingScreenController") as! LoadingScreenController

            tableView.isHidden = true
            self.progressView.isHidden = false
            self.self.progressIndicatorView.isHidden = false
            self.startTimer()

            DemosClient.sharedInstance.updatePackage2()
                .then { response -> Void in

                    print(response)

                }
                .catch { error in

                    print(error)
            }


        })

        update.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        action = [update]

    return action

}
```

Comment: You mean for selected row you doesn't want to show edit buttons ?

Comment: So, you want it to returns `nil` after the first selection?

Comment: @NiravD, yes thats correct

Comment: @AhmadF I want to return an empty array nil initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `canEditRowAt` and compare `indexPath` with `indexPathForSelectedRow` of `tableView`, if it matches return `false` otherwise return `true`. With these as of you are returning `false` it will not going to call `editActionsForRowAt` so no need to make any changes with it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow, selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This works. Whats the difference between canEditRowAt and didSelectRowAt? Would it be possible to make it work in didSelectRowAt?

Comment: @hamedabedini Welcome mate, `canEditRowAt` will call when you swipe the cell and `didSelectRowAt` is called when you tap the cell. What do you mean by **Would it be possible to make it work in didSelectRowAt?**

Comment: I was being stupid, thank you for explanation mate. Appreciate your help dearly mate :)

Comment: @hamedabedini Welcome mate :)